# Criteria query filtering an entity's OneToMany field's ManyToOne property

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I would like to get help with Criteria Query.
I want to get those students who has course in a specific room like 'math lab 1'.

Basically the java entity classes: ( + getters setters)

```
@Entity
public class Student {

   private Long id;
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
   private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList();
}

@Entity
public class Course {

   private Long id;
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private Student student;

   @ManyToOne
   private Room room;
}

@Entity
public class Room {

   private Long id;
   private String name;
}
```

I would do a query like this:

```
SELECT DISCTINCT(s) FROM Student s 
INNER JOIN Course c ON c.student = s
INNER JOIN Room r ON c.room = r
WHERE r.name = ?
```